# Missing Username on a Deleted User's Post

Tags: support, deleted-users, display-names

I recently followed a link to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196830/what-is-the-easiest-best-most-correct-way-to-iterate-through-the-characters-of-a) and read through the answers when I came upon something strange.

On the lower right corner of a post, one would usually see the username of the user who posted it, the user's avatar, and when the user posted. However, all I saw was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/360930/3386144):

[image]

The username of a now deleted user is missing. Typically, for deleted users something like `user1234567` would show up, but that's not the case here.

Why is this so? Or am I missing something?

Comment: maybe their username was a space

Comment: That's what I suspected, but it doesn't seem that way. My cursor didn't change like it usually does when hovering over text.

Comment: Could also be that deletion has changed. That post is *very* old. Perhaps at the sites beginning, users were "more" deleted.

Comment: Ah, yes, 2008.  I can hear that NullReferenceException throwing from 957 miles away.